# Can't get value of NSSingleEntryDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary, named "thisList", and I need to get the value of its key "list_collection".

Xcode indicates that the value is a "NSSingleEntryDictionary".

The value itself contains an array with yet another dictionary.

Please take a look at the screenshot:
[image]

Now, no matter what I try (objectforKey/valueforKey) or whatever type of object I initialize (NSArray/NsMutableArray/NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary) I end up with a nil value.

Apparently, I miss some essential knowledge on how to handle this.

My question: how should I initialize an object with the value of the key "list_collection".

Here is a (partial) dump of the json:

```
Printing description of thisList:
{
    archived = 0;
    "chapter_part" = "";
    "chapter_title" = "";
    comment = "";
    "cover_id" = "<null>";
    "created_at" = "2017-01-06T12:59:04.000+01:00";
    "date_created" = "06 January 2017";
    deleted = 0;
    id = 141384502;
    isMyList = 1;
    keywords =     (
    );
    "list_collection" =     {
        lists =         (
                        {
                "speech_locale" = EN;
                subject = engels;
                words =                 (
                                        {
                        word = attitude;
                    },
```

The to me most logical approach would be:

```
NSDictionary * myDic = [thisList objectForKey:@"list_collection"];
```

Note: I didn't explicitly initialize 'myDic' here.

To put things in context, here is my code:

```
 NSString * hlists = [json objectForKey:@"lists"];
    NSData* data = [hlists dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *wrtsLists = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
    Lists = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary *thisList in wrtsLists){
        WordList* theList = [[WordList alloc]init];
        theList.title = [thisList valueForKey:@"title"];
        [Lists addObject:theList];
        NSDictionary *myDic = thisList[@"list_collection"];
       >>>>this is where I put a breakpoint. myDic is nil here
    }
```

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Can you post some code and JSON data ? so we can help you out in your issue.

Comment: It doesn't matter what object type you declare your variable to be, it will not be "nil" if the key is correct. A type mismatch might (will) cause a crash later down the line, but it will not make the value nil.

Try to use the console and type "po thisList.allKeys" and see if you spell the key correctly

Comment: According to the screenshot your *most logical approach* is supposed to work. However I'd always prefer key subscription like `thisList[@"list_collection"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get "list_collection" array from "thisList" using by this code

```
NSDictionary *myDic = thisList[@"list_collection"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I figured out, that it was an Xcode problem. 
The Debug area just didn't correctly display the values of my objects.
I restarted Xcode, and things started to work as expected.
I lost several hours of my life on this. But I learned a lot, thanks to your good advises.

Answer (score -1):

Try this hope it helps You

```
NSDictionary *myDic =  [thelist valueForKey:"list_collection"];
```

Comment: Do not use `valueForKey` unless you can explain why you explicitly need KVC.